# Where can I find information on dethermalizer aerodynamics?

Tags: aerodynamics

A [dethermalizer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dethermalizer) is a *device that alters the aerodynamics of an airplane, glider etc, allowing it to descend quickly*.

Are there any sources - including equations and derivations - on dethermalizers, as (most often) used on free flight model planes?

Source: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE1ZmG-53ik).

The most detailed information I've found so far is NASA's low speed controlled deep stall sailplane tests, which contain many measurements graphs and verbal descriptions, but no math to explain this behavior.

- NASA [Technical Paper 3022](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88181main_H-1563.pdf), 1990
- NASA [Technical Memorandum 86041](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/87982main_H-1242.pdf)
- NASA [Technical Memorandum 85917](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88009main_H-1270.pdf)

Comment: That's the kind of ride that will get your passenger's attention! It looks to me like the tail is designed specifically to cause a stall for testing purposes. Is that what I'm seeing?

Comment: Based on my observation of free flight models, the slab elevator is designed to stop or reduce forward motion, stalling the wing, and ideally causing the plane to descend straight down while pitch and yaw remain approximately level.

Comment: Again based on observation - as I've seen no wind tunnel test streamlines - the main difference between a dethermalizer's operation and an ordinary "deep stall", is that with the DT, the elevator is not immersed in the turbulent wake of the stalled main wing. It maintains relatively clean airflow over the tail surfaces allowing some measure of directional and "glide angle" control. The NASA glider tests were the first intentional use of a DT on any full size aircraft that I'm aware of, however the Wright Brothers did described this apparently accidental maneuver with one of their gliders.

Comment: Correction: pitch and Roll remain approximately level, with the rudder - depending on design - allowing some yaw control.